# How to get a list of classes in a project that are no longer needed by anything in that project

Tags: java, refactoring, dependencies

Is there any way to generate a list of classes in a Java project that are no longer needed by any other classes in that project?

Here's a diagram to help illustrate the situation (I hope you enjoy my ASCII diagram since I don't have enough rep to use an image), where C and B depend on project A:

```
         A
        / \
       /   \
      C     B
```

I started refactoring by moving code from B to A, so that it could be shared by C and B.  However, now that I'm getting close to finishing refactoring, I want to check to see if there are any classes that I moved to A that can now be moved back down to B (classes that are in A but aren't using by any code in A)

Is there some tool that I can use to generate a list of such classes for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JBoss Tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) works well for this. I have used it in the past to figure out what third-party libraries are no longer needed by our project and also to learn about potentially conflicting packages/classes that are present in multiple JAR files.

Answer (score 1):

Start your program with the [-verbose:class flag](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) to the JVM. Redirect the output to a file. Exercise your program - run your tests or whatever. Grep out the name of every class loaded. Run [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) over your build output directories to make a list of all your classes. Compare the results to find anything in your build output directories that's not in the list of loaded classes.